# how to insert multiple values with foreach

Tags: php, mysql

adding checkbox values using `foreach`. the checkbox name are same.. [image]

**i tried this**

```
<?php
// checkbox name is check[]
$check = $_POST['check']; 
foreach($check as $checks => $checked)
{
 $value = $checked;
 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `db` (`db_column`) VALUES ('".$value."')"); 
}
?>
```

Comment: make check box as array

    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="your value"

Comment: that give me error.. invalid arguments blah blah blah

Comment: check it i am submit now

Comment: can you show html form you use ?

Comment: @Alex that is dynamic too large to post, but i am using same name like i post here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        <form name="form1" action="count.php" method="POST">
         <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="your value">
         <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="your value1">
         <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="your value2">
         <button type="submit" name="btn">Ok</button>
         </form>
         <?php
         if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
            $check = $_POST['check'];
            print_r($check);foreach($check as $checks => $checked){
                $value = $checked;

             $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `db` (`db_column`) VALUES ('".$value."')"); 
            }
         }
         ?>
```

Comment: dude i want to insert that in database i don't want to show that in array, tell me something likely i print_r is not handy for this situation

Comment: this is output dude                                                 INSERT INTO `db` (`db_column`) VALUES ('your value')
INSERT INTO `db` (`db_column`) VALUES ('your value1')

Answer (score 0):

PHP supports multi-dimensional request arguments. But you will need to change the form structure. I'm giving you a basic example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['example_checkbox'])) {
    foreach($_POST['example_checkbox'] as $key => $value) {
        echo "The balue of $key is $value<br />";
    }
    exit;
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="checkbox" name="example_checkbox[checkbox_1]" value="1" />1<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="example_checkbox[checkbox_2]" value="2" />2<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="example_checkbox[checkbox_3]" value="3" />3<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="example_checkbox[checkbox_4]" value="4" />4<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="example_checkbox[checkbox_5]" value="5" />5<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="example_checkbox[checkbox_6]" value="6" />6<br />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: my page isn't static i can't do that checkbox_1 , checkbox_2 they should be the same because they can be more then 6 or less then 6 in your code i only can get value from 6. in my page i am getting value dynamically from at least 30 checkbox(s)

Comment: The example will work even if you change the names to `example_checkbox[]` - it is the same, the only difference you will have is that the `$key` variable in the loop will be an integer, not a string.

Comment: let me check the suggestion

Comment: nothing same error can you please provide me sample code?